# Segmentation fault when associating optional allocatable array with optional non-allocatable dummy argument

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, intel-fortran, sles

The following Fortran code generates a segmentation fault when compiled with ifort version 19.0.3.199 without optimization (`-O0`) on SLES 15:

```
program test_prg
  call sub1()

contains

  subroutine sub1(opt)
    integer, allocatable, optional :: opt(:)
    call sub2(opt)
  end subroutine

  subroutine sub2(opt)
    integer, optional :: opt(:)
  end subroutine

end program
```

I do not intend to allocate `opt` within `sub2`, so I did not specify `allocatable` attribute there. If I make it allocatable in both subroutines or non-optional or if I pass an actual argument in the call to `sub1`, then the code finishes without errors. The same code also runs fine when compiled with gfortran from gcc version 8.3.0 20190222.

Is it a compiler bug or am I doing something illegal here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortran 2018 prohibits your use of `opt` in  `sub1`.  The restrictions on not present optional dummy arguments include (15.5.2.12):

> An optional dummy argument that is not present is subject to the following restrictions.
>
> ...
>
> (8) If it is allocatable, it shall not be allocated, deallocated, or supplied as an actual argument corresponding to an optional nonallocatable dummy argument.